# Is there any code that runs when the view controller is changed?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

Is there any global function that I can override when the view controller is changed?

Like in the app delegate?

I'm using mono touch and I want to change my navigation bar for every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple examples to help you out.

You can do these in `ViewDidLoad()`:

- Set `Title` on the controller to set the text of the title bar
- Set `NavigationBar.RightBarButtonItem` or `NavigationBar.LeftBarButtonItem` to add an additional
  button to the toolbar
- Set `NavigationBar.TintColor` to change the color of the bar

If you do these in `ViewDidLoad` it will do it for each screen or "controller" you need to setup.

If you mention which feature you need specifically, we could help you out more.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for every controller without having to copy and  paste the same code everywhere

Comment: In general, setting `Title` is something you should always do.  But for iOS 5 and above, you can use `UIAppearance`, see here: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Oct-14.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what you want to do exactly.
If it's only to change the Navigation bar for each view that is showed, you can access "this.NavigationController" from each viewcontroller. As long as they share the same UINavigationController, you can change this same navigation bar.